# How to glob only files without an extension?

Tags: python, glob

I have files like the following:

```
filename_000
filename_000.sh
filename_000.e
filename_000.o
```

Is there a way I can specify a regex inside the glob function? Something like this:

```
from glob import glob
for file in glob("filename_[0-9]{1,3}$"):
    ...
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
glob("filename_???")
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `re` module:

```
import re
import os
pattern="filename_[0-9]{1,3}$"
for file in re.findall(pattern ,'\n'.join(os.listdir())):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Just figured it out. I guess a regex would do it:

```
from glob import glob
import re

re_file = re.compile("filename_[0-9]{1,3}$")
files = glob("filename*")
files = [f for f in files if re_file.findall(f)]
```